# Probability of at least 2 occurring from 4 independent events

Tags: probability

Say you have a group of horse races, Race A,B,C,D

What is the chance of picking  at least 2 (minimum of 2 winners) winners from these 4 horse races...

The chance of winning A is :1 in 4.2 (0.238)

The chance of winning B is :1 in 2.58 (0.388)

The chance of winning C is :1 in 5    (0.200)

The chance of winning D is :1 in 1.9 or (0.526)

(all races are independent)

I have tried to work this out using the decimal value: (A * B)+ (A * C)+ (A * D) +(B * C) + (B * D) + (C * D)= 0.652 or 1 in 1.52

I have tried to use excel but when i play around in excel with the odds/probability values i can exceed 1, which means my equation is wrong

Ie changing all the values to 1 in 2 would give 0.25 = (A * B) *6 which would give 1.5 which is clearly incorrect

Thanks

EDIT: Apologies Jmoravitz it should have read "at least 2 winners"

EDIT 2: Many Thanks for the input to my question, after using the help provided i got a answer of 0.415 to 3sf or roughly 1 in 2.41 for atleast 2 winners

Comment: Are you looking for winning exactly two?  In any case, note that to win only races $A$ and $B$ you must also *lose* races $C$ and $D$

Comment: For the question of at least two winners you could approach directly., counting probability to get exactly two winners, add this to the probability of exactly three, add this to probability of getting exactly four.,  you could approach indirectly as probability of getting at least one and subtract away the probability of getting exactly one., or you could approach indirectly as 1 minus the probability of getting exactly one winner or zero winners.  I personally prefer this last approach, it seems to be the least effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** As JMoravitz already said you have to loose some races. And you should use the converse probability.

$P("\texttt{Winning at least two races}")=1-P("\texttt{Winning at most 1 race}")$

For instance, the probability of winning **exactly one** race is

$P(A)\cdot P(\overline B )\cdot P(\overline C)\cdot P(\overline D)+P(B)\cdot P(\overline A )\cdot P(\overline C)\cdot P(\overline D)+P(C)\cdot P(\overline B )\cdot P(\overline A)\cdot P(\overline D)+P(D)\cdot P(\overline B )\cdot P(\overline C)\cdot P(\overline A)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

Your are doing it wrong. Its not the method of finding atleast 2 winners.

As you have 4 persons so better to find probability of none winner or 1 winner and subtract both probabilities from 1.

No winner -

$A(Lose) \times B(Lose) \times C(Lose) \times D(Lose)$

One winner -

$A(Win) \times B(Lose) \times C(Lose) \times D(Lose)+A(Lose) \times B(Win) \times C(Lose) \times D(Lose)+A(Lose) \times B(Lose) \times C(Win) \times D(Lose)+A(Lose) \times B(Lose) \times C(Lose) \times D(Win)$

Comment: Ok thank u for your advice.

Comment: Thank you Kanwaljit Singh...i got the answer of 0.415 or 1 in 2.41

Comment: Mine pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $W_1,W_2,W_3,W_4$ be the event that $A,B,C,D$ win their race, respectively.   Then by the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion:

$$\def\Pr{\mathop{\sf P}}\begin{align}\Pr\left(\bigcup\limits_{1\leq j< k\leq 4} W_jW_k\right)~&=~{\sum\limits_{1\leq j<k\leq 4} \Pr(W_jWk)-\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j<k\leq 4}\Pr(W_iW_jW_k)+\Pr(W_1W_2W_3W_4)}\\[1ex] &=~{{\sum\limits_{1\leq j<k\leq 4} \Pr(W_j)\Pr(Wk)}-{\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j<k\leq 4}\Pr(W_i)\Pr(W_j)\Pr(W_k)}+{\Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_2)\Pr(W_3)\Pr(W_4)}}\\[1ex] &=~ {{\Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_2)}+{\Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_3)}+{\Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_4)}+{\Pr(W_2)\Pr(W_3)}+{\Pr(W_2)\Pr(W_4)}+{\Pr(W_3)\Pr(W_4)}-{\Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_2)\Pr(W_3)}-{\Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_2)\Pr(W_4)}-{\Pr(W_2)\Pr(W_3)\Pr(W_4)}+{\Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_2)\Pr(W_3)\Pr(W_4)} } \\[1ex] &=~ {{\Pr(W_1)\big(\Pr(W_2)+\Pr(W_3)+\Pr(W_4)\big)}+{\Pr(W_2)\big(\Pr(W_3)+\Pr(W_4)\big)}-{\Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_2)\big(\Pr(W_3)+\Pr(W_4)\big)}+{\Pr(W_3)\Pr(W_4)\big(\Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_2)-\Pr(W_1)-\Pr(W_2)+1\big)} }\end{align}$$

OR if you prefer:

$$\bbox[ghostwhite,1ex, border:dotted 0.1pt green]{\begin{align}\Pr(AB\cup AC\cup AD\cup BC\cup BD\cup CD) &={{\Pr(A)\big(\Pr(B)+\Pr(C)+\Pr(D)\big)}+{\Pr(B)\big(\Pr(C)+\Pr(D)\big)}-{\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\big(\Pr(C)+\Pr(D)-\Pr(C)\Pr(D)\big)}+{\Pr(C)\Pr(D)\big(1-\Pr(A)-\Pr(B)\big)}}\end{align}}$$